# Remove number and symbols from string

Tags: vb.net

i could receive files which could look like those below:

```
something.csv
something
something(3)
something(140).csv
```

So if the file at the end contain `anything(somenumber)`

and depends of file with or without extension `anything(somenumber).extension`

i want to `(somenumber)` be deleted from string. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Show us the code you've written to attempt it! Have you done any research?

Comment: is the file name always fixed? i mean will it be always <something> (ignoring extension and numbers and symbols)?

Comment: no - something is whatever you like it could be anything

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
string test="something(3)";
    test=Regex.Replace(test, @"\d", "").Replace("()","");
```

Option 2:

```
string test="something(3)";
int startindex=test.IndexOf("("); 
if (startindex>0) 
 test=test.substring(0,startindex-1);
```

Comment: besides regex - is there any other solution?

Comment: int startindex=test.IndexOf("(");  test=test.substring(0,startindex-1);

Comment: But in above case you have to check for "(" to avoid exceptions.

Comment: and what if string will not contain (number) then you second solution will work? Please put it also in answer

Comment: if i place file like this: UIPArt3MilaGroupUIAPO34mev1-mihe-2015_9_23-21_30_5_580.csv  then it will show: UIPArtMilaGroupUIAPOmev-mihe-__-___.csv

Comment: Then you can go for the second option of substring. Check whether filename contains ( or not.

Comment: can you show? I mean there could be situation that file doesn;t contain (number)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90525/discussion-between-rakesh-and-stackuser).

Comment: you mean like this?:
   If (startindex > 0) Then
            test = test.Substring(0, startindex - 1)
            test = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(test, "\d", "").Replace("()", "")
        End If

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim str As String = "something(140).csv"
  Dim newstr As String
  Dim idx1, idx2 As Integer
  idx1 = str.IndexOf("(")
  idx2 = str.IndexOf(")") + 1
  newstr = str.Replace(str.Substring(ixd1, (idx2 - ixd1)), "")
```

or you can create a function like below

```
 Private Function RemoveStringWithin(ByVal str As String, _
                                        ByVal start_char As String, _
                                        ByVal end_char As String) As String
        Dim idx1, idx2 As Integer
        idx1 = str.IndexOf(start_char)
        idx2 = str.IndexOf(end_char) + 1
        RemoveStringWithin = str.Replace(str.Substring(idx1, (idx2 - idx1)), "")
        Return RemoveStringWithin
    End Function
```

usage :

```
 Dim str As String = "something(140).csv"
 Dim str1 As String = "something<another_noise%.csv"

 str = RemoveStringWithin(str, "(", ")")
 str1 = RemoveStringWithin(str1, "<", "%")
```

Comment: this will raise error when string doesn't contain brackets like: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll on this line: RemoveStringWithin = str.Replace(str.Substring(idx1, (idx2 - idx1)), "")